# the code for adding a new integer element at the last of the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have shown here, the block including the structure declaration(outside the main function) and the function append() to add the element . So while displaying the elements , i am getting about 7 more numbers, I don't know if it's an address or something. Thanks for the help!

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node* next;
};
void append(struct node** head_add,int p)
{
   struct node* new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   struct node* ptr=(*head_add);
   new_node->data=p;
   new_node->next=NULL;
   if (*head_add == NULL) 
   { 
      *head_add = new_node; 
      return; 
   }   
   while(ptr->next!=NULL)
   ptr=ptr->next;
   ptr->next=new_node;
}
```

Note: Here is the display() function that i used:

```
void display(struct node *head)
{
   while(head->next!=NULL)
   {
       printf("%d",head->data);
       head=head->next;
   }
}
```

Edit:

```
int main()
{
    struct node *head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next=NULL;
```

then there are other stuff,,

and then here's the call in the middle of if-else :

```
else if(y==3)
        {
            printf("Enter the value to be added\n");
            scanf("%d",&p);
            append(&head,p);

        }
```

Comment: Can you show the call to `append`?

Comment: sure, i'll edit the post

Comment: You should probably add a space between the elements when you print them. The way you print your list, "7 more numbers"  might actually be a single garbage value.

Comment: @MOehm Yes I'll get that change done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dummy node at the head of the list whose data you don't initialize. That's where the garbage value comes from. In addition to that, you miss out on the last value when you display the data, because you check whether the node after the current node is null.

You could keep the dummy node and fix your code by printing `head->next->data`, but *don't do that!* The dummy node makes everything more complicated. An empty list has no nodes and its head pointer is `NULL`. So initialize your list like so:

```
struct node *head = NULL;        // empty list
```

Then fix your display function so that it visits every node:

```
void display(struct node *head)
{
     while (head != NULL) {
         printf("%d\n", head->data);
         head = head->next;
     }
}
```

Your function that appends a value already takes care of empty lists, so you don't need to change anything there.

Comment: Thanks ! I would like to add that there was another thing to correct after which it worked good.
It was that I was dynamically allocating the memory for head, which was of no use right?, so it was making an extra garbage value.

Comment: Yes. `struct node *head = NULL;`does not allocate any memory, so that "correction" is already in my answer. Use allocation only if you want to create things, fo rexample npodes in the list. An empty list has no nodes, so no allocation is needed.